# Conditional Cumulative Sum Macro

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I have been stuck on my first subroutine for a while now and have tried researching my problem but am fairly new to VBA so have had little luck finding anything specific. I have a rather large spreadsheet (56090 rows) which is full of daily data points for a bunch of items with unique names. The item name is located in column D and the data I need is located in columns F and H. I am trying to create a cumulative sum for each day in column K that resets when it reaches a new item name (by checking the current row item name with the previous row item name). The code I have seems to do the trick but stops running at row 22510 (no error, just the sum values after this row are wrong).

```
Sub cum(ByVal DataPoints As Long)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim index As Long
Dim runningCum As Long

runningCum = 0

For index = 3 To DataPoints
'Set cell to Cum Oil column at index row
    cel = Cells(index, "K")
    'If the well name in previous row is equal to well name in index row, add oil values to runningCum
    If Cells(index - 1, "D") = Cells(index, "D") Then
        runningCum = runningCum + Cells(index, "F") + Cells(index, "H")
    'Otherwise, reset runningCum
    Else
        runningCum = 0
    End If
    'Set the Cum Oil cell value to the runningCum
    cel = runningCum
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use very simple formula in `K3` and stretch it down:

  `=IF(D2=D3,K2+F3+H3,0)`
- but if you prefer VBA, try to change in your code:

  `cel = Cells(index, "K")` to `Set cel = Cells(index, "K")`

  and `cel= runningCum` to `cel.Value = runningCum`
- or you can use following simple code (it calculates values using formulas, and then deletes formulas and leaves only values):

  ```
  Sub cum(ByVal DataPoints As Long)

      With Range("K3:K" & DataPoints)
          .Formula = "=IF(D2=D3,K2+F3+H3,0)"
          .Calculate
          .Value = .Value
      End With
  End Sub
  ```

Comment: Well now I feel silly that the solution was staring me in the face all along. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something like this:

```
Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, aa, ab, ac As String

If Trim(range("A1").Value) <> "name" Then a = " Header for Column A is incorrect "

If Trim(range("B1").Value) <> "type" Then a = " Header for Column B is incorrect "

MsgBox (" The following error(s) have occured " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & a & b)
```

I have to write the above for all the variables I have declared.